# Spark, numbering rows in groups

Tags: apache-spark

OK, I may be way off here. But I'm struggling to learn the basics of Spark by digging through a rather minimal dataset with football matches (from http://www.football-data.co.uk/englandm.php).

What I have already done:

- Read all files with all matches in the English leagues.
- 'convert' the csv-rows to a case class called Match.

Code:

```
case class Match(
              startTime: Date,
              homeTeam: String,
              awayTeam: String,
              homeGoals: Int,
              awayGoals: Int,
              league: String,
              season: String,
              round: Int = -1,
}

object Parser {
    def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {

        val spark = SparkSession.builder()
            .appName("test")
            .getOrCreate()

        import spark.implicits._

        val data = spark.read
            .textFile("data/football-data.co.uk/1516/E*.csv")
            .filter(s => !s.startsWith("Season,Div,Date")) // remove headers.
            .map(s => s.split(","))
            .map(a => createMatch(a))
    }
}
```

**Now I would like to number each match, within each league and season.**

I'm drawing a blank here. Have tried partitioning and grouping without any luck and desperately need some pointers.

Am I way off trying to do this in Spark, since I need to keep a state in my iterations over league+season?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help provided in rouge-one's answer I ended up doing this:

```
val baseData = spark.read
  .option("header", true)
  .option("dateFormat", "dd/MM/yy")
  .schema(schema)
  .csv("data/football-data.co.uk/1516/E[0,C].csv")

baseData
  .select("Date", "Div", "Season", "HomeTeam", "AwayTeam")
  .withColumn("round", row_number() over (partitionBy("Div", "Season", "HomeTeam") orderBy("Date")))
  .show(100)
```

From here I can now create my Match-objects.

The schema definition looks like this:

```
val schema =
  StructType(
    Array(
      StructField("Season",          StringType, false),
      StructField("Div",          StringType, false),
      StructField("Date",         DateType, false),
      StructField("HomeTeam",     StringType, false),
      StructField("AwayTeam",     StringType, false),
      StructField("FTHG",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("FTAG",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("FTR",     StringType, false),
      StructField("HTHG",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HTAG",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HTR",     StringType, false),
      StructField("Referee",     StringType, false),
      StructField("HS",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AS",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HST",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AST",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HF",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AF",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HC",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AC",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HY",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AY",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("HR",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("AR",     IntegerType, false),
      StructField("B365H",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("B365D",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("B365A",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BWH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BWD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BWA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("IWH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("IWD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("IWA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("LBH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("LBD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("LBA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("WHH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("WHD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("WHA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("VCH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("VCD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("VCA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("Bb1X2",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMxH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAvH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMxD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAvD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMxA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAvA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbOU",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMx>2.5",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAv>2.5",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMx<2.5",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAv<2.5",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAHh",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMxAHH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAvAHH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbMxAHA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("BbAvAHA",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSCH",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSCD",     DoubleType, false),
      StructField("PSCA",     DoubleType, false)
    )
  )
```

(This in not very helpful for my usecase, since I can't calculate round accurately using this dataset. But still great practice.)

Answer (score 1):

Row number generation over a partition/window are best done by ROW_NUMBER function provided by spark-sql.

```
data.createOrReplaceTempView("temp_table")

val newDF = spark.sql(
"""
SELECT 
 <list other columns required>
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY league,season ORDER BY startTime) as slno
FROM temp_table;
""");
```